# checking free memory on cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I tried to check amount of free memory in cygwin, but it says that `free` is not found. Is it possible to do in cygwin, if so what package do I need to install?

```
$ free
-bash: free: command not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `free` command is part of the `procps` package.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo 
...
MemFree:         1552148 kB
...
SwapFree:        8050832 kB
```

This command lists the contents of the special file `/proc/meminfo`, which reports the current distribution and utilization of memory, one line per item, including the free memory on the line beginning with "MemFree". This value matches the value reported by Windows(TM) task manager for free memory.

The `/proc` file system is part of Cygwin base package, intended to mimic its Linux version, described in [kernel document proc.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt). Search for the word "meminfo" twice.

For the meaning of special files and their differences from Linux, see the [Cygwin document using-specialnames.html](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html). Look for the title "The `/proc` filesystem".

The line with SwapFree shows the amount of swap space remaining. If the physical memory is mostly free, the swap should also be free, at its initial maximum, typically equal to the physical memory size. A lower value shows the presence of a memory hog/leak, may lead to general slowdown of the system, growth of the swap file (pagefile.sys), consume disk space, and require terminating the memory hog and/or a system restart to return to normal.

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit? What is that command, how does it answer the question?

Comment: That special file shows you the meminfo as text. `free` just formats it in a different way